# Why when I tried to insert some values in the table with python the output it’s none?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have this code

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db_name")
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO directedEdges (`originLbl`, `targetLbl`) VALUES 
              ('user1@enron.com', 'user2@enron.com' )")
data = cursor.fetchone()
print data
```

but when I execute this script the output is None and and I can't insert the values in the db. Why ?

In a first moment I thought it was a problem whit db connection, but if I execute

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db_name")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM directedEdges")
data = cursor.fetchone()
print data
```

I see the content of the table directedEdges.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issued the `cursor.fetchone()` command immediately after inserting into the database. You don't have any queried data like that. You need to have queried some data before using `fetchone()`. Try this:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db_name")
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO directedEdges (`originLbl`, `targetLbl`) VALUES 
              ('user1@enron.com', 'user2@enron.com' )")
# Commit your insert
db.commit()

# Query for data
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM directedEdges")

data = cursor.fetchone()
print data
```

Comment: You can't insert the values? What's happening when you run the ```cursor.execute``` insert statement? Is it throwing an error? If yes, what's the error? What is it showing?